decodeURIComponent(encoded) - using BigQuery
I use function decodeURIComponent(encoded) in Big Query to decode search terms withing specific URL but sometimes getting this error

For example, let's take this particular URL - 'https://kockashop.hu/legok/talalatok/1?key=/%%C2%A7!'
where is the problem Please? Why function doesn't work good in this case, but getting the above error.
Any help is welcome!
In 98% of cases the function works well, but why does it sometimes throw this error?
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trtrtrt-1611138397284.Live.decode_url(encoded STRING) RETURNS STRING LANGUAGE js AS R"""
return decodeURIComponent(encoded);
""";

Your example seems to be a malformed URI. Maybe you need to treat this cases with a try/catch or something else. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

Thank you! I will try to identify wrong URL first.

The problem with this is, the URL has an invalid percent-encoded sequence. Double %% is not recognized or it doesn’t have any corresponding character. Try to remove or change with only one %. Or in your case, if that is a corresponding key, try to update the key with a valid percent-encoded sequence.
